# Automaticly show email content on a webpage?

Tags: html, email

For a certain application I need to show the attachment of an email on a website.. (it's a private site so not open for public).. the attachment is a html file. The file is emailed to my specified address every 30 mins. I need to display these contents on a autorefreshing webpage. What the easiest way to get this done? I was thinking writing a cronscript that checks the mailserver every 30 mins, downloads the attachment and places it in a certain place.. but maybe someone outthere has a better idea?

Comment: what you mean by autorefreshing?.. You presume user having this page open for more than 30 minutes for update to happen?.. Then you need to just schedule periodic updates of this page in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks reasonable to split this task into parts. Craft one cronscript which downloads incoming messages to an ordered storage  (file system will suffice, if you are cautious about backing it up). Then craft a webpage that present some view of that storage.

Another, more straightforward solution would be to have one single webpage script which polls email server, downloads latest file and displays it. If it works too slow, you may just add some disk caching with proper timing out. This is for the case if you have a single message to display.

Comment: Yeah guess I will go for the cron option then.. thanks for the brainstorm :)

Comment: I'd recommend to start with less complicated, second solution ;)